# Why iOS Firebase first_open count doesn't match active users count?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have launched a new app on iOS and Android in January 2017 which integrates Firebase for analytics purpose.

My problem:
When I look at the analytics for the iOS app on the whole app life, I see significantly less `first_open` events than `active users` :

`first_open` count: 228

`active users` count: 759 (similar to the number of downloads in iTunesConnect)

I don't have this problem for the Android app.
This is breaking my conversion funnel, any help would be great !